# Could not load type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.Tracing.DiagnosticsListener'

Tags: mono, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I created a .NET Core web application and tried to run on ubuntu with the help of mono 4.4 target framework 4.5.1, I am facing following exception.

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.Tracing.DiagnosticsListener' from assembly 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Initialize () <0x40a768d0 + 0x0001f> in :0 
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build () <0x40a5fee0 + 0x00167> in :0 
>   at Socioboard.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in /home/glb-014/Documents/Socioboard/src/Socioboard/Program.cs:14 
>   [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.Tracing.DiagnosticsListener' from assembly 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Initialize () <0x40a768d0 + 0x0001f> in :0 
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build () <0x40a5fee0 + 0x00167> in :0

and here is my project.json

```
   {
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Serilog": "2.0.0-rc-598",
"Serilog.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-10110",
"Serilog.Sinks.ColoredConsole": "2.0.0-beta-700",
"Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile": "2.0.0-rc-703",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"MongoDB.Bson": "2.2.4",
"MongoDB.Driver": "2.2.4",
"MySql.Data": "6.9.8",
"MySql.Data.Entity": "6.9.8",
"Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.3",
"NHibernate.Linq": "1.0.0",
"StackExchange.Redis": "1.1.603",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
},

"tools": {
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
"version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
"imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
}
},

"frameworks": {
"net451": {
"frameworkAssemblies": {
"System.Xml": "4.0.0.0"
},
"dependencies": {
"NHibernate": "4.0.4.4000"
}
}
},

"buildOptions": {
"emitEntryPoint": true,
"preserveCompilationContext": true
},

"runtimeOptions": {
"gcServer": true
},

"publishOptions": {
"include": [
"wwwroot",
"Views",
"appsettings.json",
"web.config"
]
},

"scripts": {
"postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
}
}
```

please help me to fix this issue.